# Is there a way for Postgres to overwrite one column if the other column is true?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a `Comment` table that I don't want to delete, but merely overwrite data to destroy the information within it.

I would like to add a boolean `is_deleted?` and if it equals `true`, have it overwrite the `:body` column with "This comment has been deleted"  order to "delete" it but retain the other data I need in order to preserve relationships.

Is there a way to do such a thing with Postgres? Or is the only solution to write a ruby method to overwrite data?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple approach is to use a view:

```
create view v_table as
    select . . .,
           (case when is_deleted then 'This comment has been deleted'
                 else comment
            end) as comment
    from t;
```

Then query the view instead of the table to get the behavior that you want.

Comment: SQL is a bit of a mystery to me. Can you explain a bit further as to what this is doing and a bit more on how to implement it?

Comment: @Antonio . . . I'm not sure what needs explaining.  A view is a way of pre-packaging a query result set so you can use it like a table.  The answer gives the definition of the view (the `. . .` represents all the other columns in the table).

Comment: I have used Rails and postgres in pretty standard ways so I've never had to use a postgres "view". I'm guessing I would implement your code in some sort of method?

Comment: @Antonio . . . Your question is tagged Postgres.  A view is a fundamental part of Postgres (or any database).  You create the view in the database:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html.